# weka training result return 0 in java

Tags: weka

I am new to weka. I am using weka in java to train my result on android phone.I loaded arff file when the program started.

In the training set, I only set the nominal result to @attribute Result {1,2,3,4}.  Therefore, I thought, I should only receive 1,2,3,4 as a result. But, when I train the data real-timely on the phone, a lot of 0 or -1 appeared in the result.

My question is: is that possible for Weka to return a classification result outside the nominal value set? Like in my case, I set the result in the trainig set as 1,2,3,4, but it returned a lot of 0.

Thanks a lot

Below is my code.

```
    int result = 0;
                try {       
                    Instance inst = new DenseInstance(1.0,vals);
                    data.setClassIndex( data.numAttributes() - 1 );
                    data.add(inst);
                    inst.setDataset(data);
                    result = (int) m_classifier.classifyInstance(inst);

                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to debug the code, you may attach weka source code `weka-src.jar` to `weka.jar` and then break into the function to see what happened.

It's quite hard that someone encountered exactly the same problem with you. So you may need to try to debug by yourself. I think it's the most effective way for you and for now.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But, is that possible in weka to return a value outside the nominal value set?

Comment: I think all the values in the nominal sets have their own indices. For example, for `type = {yes, no}`, the index of `yes` is `0`, and `no` is `1`. `Attribute.value(index)` returns the name of value according to `index`. Did I rightly get your question?

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer reminded me to check this problem. Now it solved.